# How does live-streaming work from a high level perspective?

Tags: android, mobile, live-streaming

I'm starting to work on an app that requires some live-streaming functionality, but I realized I don't really understand how the technology works. Could anyone explain, or at least point me in the right direction, how live-streaming works at a relatively high level? What are the SDK's, like the ones Agora or Bambuser provide, doing that allow me to achieve a live-streaming functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first choice for me would ExoPlayer from Google. They had great documentation as well https://exoplayer.dev/live-streaming.html

Comment: Awesome. This looks promising. Let me check it out.